# Unable to access instance Permission denied (publickey) after installing vsftpd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I am unable to access my ec2 ssh , the last thing i am sure that i've did is created AMI in aws console and then installed vsftpd:-

```
sudo apt install vsftpd
```

That's it.

Now when i am trying to access ec2 ssh i get the following error:-

```
ssh -i sshkey.pem ubuntu@ec2-00-000-000-000.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com
ubuntu@ec2-00-000-000-000.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Installing vsftpd can never have an impact on your SSH access.
the only things I think of:

1. you regenerated ssh keys for ubuntu user.
2. you rebooted your ec2 server and with elatic IP attached and now it has a different IP.
3. your ssh key has wrong permissions, it should be 600

Comment: 1. its impossible i did that,the only thing i am sure i did is just installed ftp server 2. i am accessing SSH using public DNS 3. I checked the permission